# Will I have to create separate Apple IDs for two iOS devices to message each other?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have one Apple ID that I use for both my iPhone and my wife's iPhone. In iOS5, if we want to message to each other using iMessage, will one of us need to create a separate AppleID? And if so, will that affect apps that we've downloaded to the device using the other Apple ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to create separate Apple ID's for the iPhone because iMessage also works by using the phone number.

However if you have two wi-fi only iPad's or iPod touch's then you will just have to use separate e-mail address.

[image: There you have it]